# How to create a rectangle with centered circle shape and icon inside of it in Android?

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I'm trying to create a shape visible above a BottomNavigationView (BottomSheetDialog peek). Any ideas on how to recreate it in the app?

[image: Intended effect]

I've been trying with layer-list which looks fine on the preview but gets flattened while setting it up as a background for a view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="-13dp" android:start="120dp" android:end="120dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/turquoise"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/turquoise"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_bottomsheetdialog_arrow_up"
          android:bottom="15dp"
          android:start="130dp"
          android:end="130dp"
          android:top="-10dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

XML preview:

[image: XML Result in preview]

Drawable applied to the View in the layout

```
   <View android:id="@+id/view_bottomSheetDialog_accentDivider"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:background="@drawable/drawable_bottom_sheet_dialog"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      android:layout_height="30dp"/>
```

[image]

I've also been thinking about workarounds such as BottomNavigationView with centered FloatingActionButton, or just 2 views (rectangle + circle shape with icon) centered in ConstraintLayout.

Any pointers on how to do this or code would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

**Since I've already figured it out, I'll post my solution here**

I've removed negative margin, add some positive one to a rectangle and made use of ImageView with android:src"@drawable..." instead of a raw View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:end="200dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:start="200dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="48dp"
                android:height="@dimen/bottomdialog_peek_height" />
            <solid android:color="@color/turquoise" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/turquoise" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_bottomsheetdialog_arrow_up"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

</layer-list>
```

And here's the ImageView:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_bottomSheetDialog_peek"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/drawable_bottom_sheet_dialog"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/bottom_sheet_dialog_peek" />
```